# How to remove duplicates when using window function to sort groupings of records and selecting minimum value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, window-functions

I am running this query below.

```
WITH CTE_Sort
AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (
            PARTITION BY sendid
            ,subscriberkey
            ) AS aggregates
        ,*
    FROM xtemp.[Stage_Clicks_marketing]
    )
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY eventdate ORDER BY eventdate DESC
        ) AS datesort
    ,aggregates
    ,sendID
    ,subscriberkey
    ,eventdate
FROM CTE_Sort
GROUP BY aggregates
    ,sendID
    ,subscriberkey
    ,eventdate
```

This returns this set of data.

[image]

Each unique grouping is sorted by a combination of sendid and subscriberkey, the aggregates column states how many times this record occurs. I would like to select only individual groupings by the oldest possible date, the current result set returns multiple dates with all other columns having the same values. How can I format my query to return only 1 record for each grouping that will have the oldest possible date?

For example, in the picture above for the first grouping of `SendID = 10548` and `SubscriberKey = 0032L000016loZeQAI`. I would only like to return the record with the `EventDate = 2020-11-18 17:28:12.0000000`. The oldest date. I don't want the additional date that occured after the older date to be returned.

Comment: Seems `ROW_NUMBER` should be in your CTE as well, and then you should be filtering to where the value of the `ROW_NUMBER` expression evaluates to `1`.

Comment: @Larnu would you be able to show me this with the query I posted modified? I apologize I'm still fairly new to SQL Server so I'm not fully understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I am reading between the lines correctly, then you need to put the `ROW_NUMBER` expression in the CTE, and then filter on that in the outer `WHERE`. This is, however, untested as the question only contains images of text:

```sql
WITH CTE_Sort AS(
    SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sendid,subscriberkey) AS aggregates,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sendid,subscriberkey ORDER BY eventdate DESC) AS RN,
           sendID,
           subscriberkey,
           eventdate
    FROM xtemp.[Stage_Clicks_marketing])
SELECT aggregates,
       sendID,
       subscriberkey,
       eventdate
FROM CTE_Sort
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I only had to change the DESC to ASC on the order by eventdate column, that got me the records with the oldest dates.